# Check if Google Maps Android V2 didLoad / isCached Map (OFFLINE MODE)

Tags: android, maps, offline-caching

Hey I want to be able to manually check or subscribe to a service which can notify me if the map was unable to load (in offline mode) due to it not being cached at the deep enough level.

This would be similar to the v1 method of map.canCoverCenter();

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/index

I have had a look through the documentation for v2 but can't see anything around this.

Any help will be very useful

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for this, so you may want to add a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

Also check this answer: [How can I detect pogrammatically whether a Google Map was actually loaded on Android with API v2 (e.g. when network is not available)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845351/how-can-i-detect-pogrammatically-whether-a-google-map-was-actually-loaded-on-and/15849021#15849021)