# how to write code for save selected area on Google map to make offline map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an android app using Google map V2, i am willing to provide an option for end user  i.e "Make offline" like this [www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-download-offline-maps-in-google-maps/](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-download-offline-maps-in-google-maps/).
Can any one tell me how to integrate code in my project for above requirement.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Google android maps V2 automatically caches the map when the user uses the map fragment and stores the tiles in a specific location.  Refer this :

[How can I detect pogrammatically whether a Google Map was actually loaded on Android with API v2 (e.g. when network is not available)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845351/how-can-i-detect-pogrammatically-whether-a-google-map-was-actually-loaded-on-and/15849021#15849021)